# Is it acceptable to ask for advice on finding a specific document online that you cannot find anywhere?

Tags: discussion

I need a specific text (a government document) that I'm hoping is accessible in an online archive somewhere. I've looked everywhere. Is it acceptable to ask this community for advice or possible archives? As someone who is moving into unfamiliar territory, this is now a regular occurrence for me.

Comment: (1) Did you ask a librarian to help you? (2) Is there any reason the document is not Google searchable and you think some of us may know how to find it? That is, what makes you believe some of us is actually better in finding the document than your librarian?

Comment: Just to reinforce what @scaaahu said -- most of the universities I've been at/visited/had friends attend have had research librarians who are dedicated to a particular topic (or set of topics). They're the "first responders" of academic research questions in my opinion.

Comment: The document is not google searchable or, if it is available, then it is hard to find. My hope was that someone might know of a repository that google does not show or which it does not catalogue. I think the librarian will be the next stop. It's not the first thing I think of -- I just automatically think 'internet' and am only just discovering the power of the librarian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have already at least a couple of questions on how to access "inaccessible" documents:

1. [What do you do when you find yourselves with an unreadable/inaccessible paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7797/20058)
2. [Literature searches in publications when you have limited access to journals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/63369/20058)

If the related answers don't help you, I think you can certainly ask another question, but please address the following points:

- What of the related questions and answers does not apply to your case, otherwise your question will be probably closed as duplicate.
- Since you are asking about a government document, specify which country you are in.

Comment: I won't ask the question in the main forum until I've tried the librarian.